# Why keyDown method does not work in Cocoa macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want use keyDown method to see which key pressed in keyboard but it does not work also my computer makes sounds to tell the key even does not work.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  
    }
 
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(event)
    }

}
```

Comment: you are using `keyDown` correctly in that code snippet. so the problem is elsewhere. you'll have to provide more information in order for this to be diagnosed.

Comment: I do not have any other codes to show, is the codes in my question works for you?

Comment: As I recall, events walk the responder chain until an object in the chain accepts the event. Is your view controller on-screen, and part of the responder chain? (Sorry, I mostly work in iOS lately and am rusty on MacOS.)

Comment: @DuncanC, you are correct.  The responder chain for events starts at the `firstResponder` view of whatever window is the `keyWindow`.  If that view doesn't respond to that particular event, it checks its `superView`, and then it's `superView` until the view hierarchy is exhausted, then it tries the window, and finally the application.   No controllers are involved in the event responder chain, though some key events can trigger action messages which use a more elaborate chain that includes view/window/application delegates.

Comment: @Milen, the answers and comments given tell you why your `keyDown(with:)` isn't being called, but they can't tell you how to exactly what you want to do, because you haven't actually said what that is.  If you give a use case that describes what you're trying to accomplish, it's more likely we can give a useful solution.

Comment: @ChipJarred: thanks, I want watch key press and if it is equal with: `command + F` then I want run an action, but i cannot even read what key got pressed.

Comment: The much better way to respond to command keys is to have one of your app's menus map to command F, and have that broadcast an IBAction that your view controller responds to.

Comment: If you assign cmd-F as `keyEquivalent` for an `NSMenuItem`  in some menu that is in the main menu (the menu bar at the top of the screen), along with it's `action` to be `Selector` for whatever it is you want to do, it will be detected by the `NSApplication` which will dispatch the selector using the command responder chain.  You can disable the menu item when it doesn't apply.

Comment: @DuncanC: thanks for help, I can do that way no issue there, I want without menu item.

Comment: @ChipJarred: thanks, I know that way, that is easy for me, but I do not want to have menu item.

Comment: @DuncanC's comment regarding broadcasting an `IBAction` is basically the same as mine.  It's a bit more storyboard oriented, while I prefer a more programmatic approach, but they boil down the same idea.

Comment: @Milen, you don't have to have a menu item, but that would be more in line with Apple's UI guidelines.   You should be able override `performKeyEquivalent(with:)->Bool` for your  main content `NSView`, which could then check if the event is a keydown `cmd-F` event then call a method in the `ViewController`.  I think a slightly more flexible design would be to implement the `performKeyEquivalent(with:) -> Bool` in `ViewController` and have the override for the `NSView` simply forward to the `ViewController`.

Comment: @ChipJarred: I do not want to an item in menu with shortcut of `cmd-F` but do want have just a shortcut of `cmd-F`, if can show the codes that do the job, I will accept it. but I do not want have any menu item.

Comment: I added an answer with code.  I have to confess that as I was writing it, I became pressed for time, so I didn't create a project and try it.  The basic idea should work for you, though obviously you'll need to adapt it to the specifics of your app.  If you have a problem getting it to work, comment on my answer to let me know.

Comment: @ChipJarred: thanks, I will try to test or use it and i say the results.

Comment: Good luck finding an answer you like

Comment: I deleted my answer.  My desire to help any further has been exhausted.

Comment: @ChipJarred: if you undelete your answer, I'll upvote it. The OP may be an ingrate, but it might be of benefit to future readers.

Comment: @TomHarrington: same for you, can you undelete your answer? Even if it was not useful for the OP, it may be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Only the responders in the current responder chain get a shot at handling events like key events, and then only if some other responder in the chain doesn't handle it first. So, you'll need to make sure that your view controller is managing a view that's the keyboard focus when the event actually takes place, *and* that the focused view doesn't handle the event itself.